# Can't open bitlocker with flash drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb-flash-drive, bitlocker, tpm

I have activated Bitlocker on my Windows 7-64 bit Ultimate machine.  The system put the key on a thumb drive.  The system will not open with the key on the thumb drive.  It is the same key that printed out; and the same key that is stored in the machine.  Could it be a corrupted .tpm file, or does anyone know how to have the computer regerate all key and tpm file information?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question exactly how BitLocker is configured on your computer. For an overview of your settings, open an elevated command prompt and type `manage-bde C: -status` (assuming your OS drive is C:). You can also use the manage-bde command line utility to add/remove BitLocker protectors.

For a more user-friendly (though less flexible) way of adding/removing protectors, right click your OS drive in explorer and click "Manage BitLocker" to manage your keys via a UI.